# Regex matching a space after extension PCRE (php)

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I am trying to migrate a fairly large and quite old database, one of the columns consists of file names. The problem is that in this one field there can be multiple filenames seperated by a space. 
For example:

`"Filename.mp3 file anem.mid fi le nam e.rm"`

I was trying to split these string with `preg_split()`, the closest regex I could come up with is

`/(?<=\.[\w]{3})(\s)/`

I know that `/(?<=\.[\w]+)(\s)/` would not work since in PCRE a lookbehind has to have a fixed width. And since this is a music DB there are unconventional extentions aswell.

Any suggestions?

Comment: mmmm nasty! someone who's a regex genius will get this for you, I predict. Meanwhile, if it were my problem, I would do what you're doing (try like hell, then ask for help (-: ) and if that didn't work, I would sigh and break down the processing of this string into multiple steps. Maybe split on the extensions with `/\.[a-z]+\b/` and capture the stuff in between the delimiters; left-trim anything after the delimiter; concatenate... something like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this regex for split:

```
~\.\w+\K\h+~
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pm9HxO/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\.`: Match literal dot
- `\w+`: Match 1+ word characters
- `\K`: Reset matched info (forget about match data)
- `\h+`: Match 1+ horizontal whitespaces

Comment: Thank you very much, didn't know about the `\K`!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regex then this is a viable solution:

```
<?php
$filename = "Filename.mp3 file anem.mid fi le nam e.rm";

// Temp storage for a single file's pieces
$new_filename = [];

// Store whole files
$filenames = [];

// Split up the string based on spaces
$spaces = explode( ' ', $filename );

// Loop the pieces broken by a space
foreach( $spaces as $piece )
{
    // just keep adding pieces to this array
    $new_filename[] = $piece;

    // if this piece contains a period then we have a whole filename
    if( strpos( $piece, '.' ) !== false )
    {
        // add this whole filename to the list by rejoining the temp var on spaces
        $filenames[] = implode( ' ', $new_filename );

        // reset the temp variable
        $new_filename = [];
    }
}

print_r( $filenames );
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Filename.mp3
    [1] => file anem.mid
    [2] => fi le nam e.rm
)
```